# Android 9-Patch scaling issue

Tags: android, background, scale, nine-patch

I am having scaling problems when using the 9-patch images for the background of EditText fields. I have a table which stretches the entire width, inside here I have the following tablerow which fills the width of the table.

The problem is that I am using a 9-patch image as the background but the edit text field is not stretching to the entire width, it only stretches to the width of the hint text.

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_username"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hint_enterUsername"
        android:hint="@string/hint_enterUsername"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edittext_textsize"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/background_field_top" />

</TableRow>
```

I can see in the graphical view that the width of the row does stretch but the EditText field does not, as shown in the attached image

[image: Graphical View]

Has anyone any ideas on how to make the edittext stretch to the entire size? The following is the 9-patch image I'm using.

[image: 9-patch image]

Comment: Can you include the 9-patch image ?

Comment: Hi @yoah, I've added the 9-patch image above, does it look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your is working fine for me ..i am using my own 9 patch... here is my code :

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_username"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/areanumber"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="hello" />
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>
```

here areanumber is my 9 patch image... just try to wrap your code inside linearlayout
i implemented your 9 patch image and its also working fine

[image]

Comment: thanks very much for your details comment. I have tested as you stated above and it works for me. But when I try to add it to a tablelayout (here you have no tablelayout, just tablerow), it doesn't work. Would you have any idea on why it doesn't work, or even be able to check by surrounding your rows with a tablelayout and see does it work for you?

Comment: hey i got the solution : what you have to do is just give weightsum to your tableRow i.e " android:weightSum="1" "   and give  android:layout_weight="1" to your EditText.

Comment: Why place a TableRow inside a LinearLayout? Read the documentation at Android Developers, it will then behave as a LinearLayout. That is why android:weightsum now is valid. You said you wanted to use a TableLayout? With this solution there is no need for the TableRow.

Comment: yes i know , i implement this code by using both linearlayout and tablelayoyut .... read my second comment... i didn't edited my code(answer) but i gave the desired answer as per question ... while using tablelayout we have to give weightsum to get required answer

Answer (score 2):

From Android Developers documentation on [TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)

> A layout that arranges its children horizontally. **A TableRow should
>   always be used as a child of a TableLayout.** If a TableRow's parent is
>   not a TableLayout, the TableRow will behave as an horizontal
>   LinearLayout.

@Nipun Gogia answer is not correct, why put a TableRow (behaving like a Horizontal LinearLayout) inside a LinearLayout with only **one** EditText child?

You should instead place the EditText view as a direct child of the [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html), it will then be displayed as a single row that spans all the table columns. And you can add more TableRow's and Columns if you want.

Stretch a background image of a EditText View with Nine-Patch:

You need to edit the 9-patch rule of the 9.png file setting the stretchable area of the image, place the top rule (black 1px line) in the middle of the image, now it is only stretching at the transparent end leaving the image un stretched.
Learn how to her: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Importent! remember to save the image with the extension .9.png

---

Nine-patch Image saved with file extension: background.**9**.png

[image]

---

Modified smaller image, it will look the same as the above because of the nine-patch rules.

[image: modified image]

---

Modified image, but with a non stretchable height.

[image]

---

*Note: if downloading the images above with "save image as..", remember to add **.9.png** to the file name for it to work.*

Comment: Hi @hsigmond, thanks for the comment. I've checked this link and created my 9-patch with what I felt it should look like. I have included my 9-patch image in my original post, would you mind having a quick look at it and see does it look ok?

Comment: top rule only needs to be 1px placed in the middle of the image (this i where you want it to stretch equally to both sides), left side should be 1px on top and bottom in the transparent area since the height is set by the image and no need to stretch it. right and bottom rule is where you want the text to be displayed inside the image (like padding) and it looks ok (can't see the bottom black line)

Comment: And try this Nine-Patch Editor, I think it's much better then the one provided in the SDK. http://weblookandfeel.com/nine-patch-editor/

Comment: Hi @GrahamB I downloaded your image file and noticed that it did not have the correct nine-patch file name extension. see updated answer.

Comment: Obs!, Looks like the .9. is removed when uploading images here, so if you download the images, add .9.png to the file name.

Comment: thanks very much for all your comments. I have edited the 9-patch image as you stated. I have made sure that the .9 is at the end, as you said it removes this when uploaded as part of the question, so that's all fine. I have tested it as "Nipun Gogia" says below and it works fine, but it's when I try to stick it into a tablelayout it doesn't work, have you any idea on why that would be

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your image file name is background_field_top.9.png (make sure that the .9. is there)
I made small changes to your image, so that the corner rounding is smoother, but that is not the core issue. [image: suggsted image]
If this does not help, check if the background works well without the table, to isolate if the issue is the layout or the background image.

Comment: Hi @yoah, thanks very much for this. I have tested the 9-patch without the tablelayout, so as "Nipun Gogia" stated below, and it works fine, it's when I try to stick it into a tablelayout it does not work, why would this be?